# laravel get list of users only email verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

When I try to get the list of users from `User:all()`, it shows me the users who also are not email verifed.

So to avoid the above situation, I am writing the following code.

```
$users = User::with('selfie')->whereNotNull('email_verified_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

let me know if there is any other shorter way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define scope https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

in User Model

```
public function scopeVerified($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('email_verified_at');
}
```

and our query will looks like

```
$users = User::with('selfie')
->verified()
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

```
$users = User::whereNOTNULL('email_verified_at')->get();
```

You get all list

Comment: yes, I am doing the same as you can see in my post. But I am want the same result from User::all();